# How to get the current minutes

Tags: groovy

How can I get the current minute?

I tried `new Date().minutes` but it seems that `minutes` is deprecated.

Is there a better way to get the current minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMinutes%28%29) of `Date.getMinutes()`:

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE).

Comment: `groovy:000> Calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: static java.util.Calendar.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [12]
Possible solutions: get(int), set(int, int), getAt(int), set(java.util.Map), grep(), next()
`

Comment: @user3029394 `Calendar.instance[ Calendar.MINUTE ]` or `Calendar.instance.get( Calendar.MINUTE )`